# Prove that if $\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]\leq \mathbb{E}[g(X)]$ for every nondecreasing function $g$ then $F_X\le F_Y$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X,Y$ random variables. Every coninuous and not-decreasing monotone function $g:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ fulfills $\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]\leq \mathbb{E}[g(X)]$.  Prove that $F_X(t)\leq F_Y(t)$.

I don't have any initial idea to solve it.

Comment: What do you know about Distribution Functions?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann Stieltjes Integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: For a fixed $t$ and $\epsilon>0$, define $g_\epsilon(x)$ as 
$$g_\epsilon(x)=\begin{cases}0,\quad x\le t\\\frac{x-t}{\epsilon},\quad t<x\le t+\epsilon\\1,\quad t+\epsilon<x\end{cases}.
$$ We can see that $g_\epsilon \uparrow 1_{(t,\infty)}(x)$ as $\epsilon\to 0$. Now, by the assumption it holds that
$$
E[g_\epsilon(Y)]\leq E[g_\epsilon(X)],\quad\forall \epsilon>0.
$$ From this fact, deduce that
$$
P(t<Y)=E[1_{\{t<Y\}}]\le E[1_{\{t<X\}}]=P(t<X)
$$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. (e.g. by monotone convergence theorem)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use Integration by Parts of the Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\,dF_X(t)$$

and

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\,dF_Y(t)$$

Then use the fact that $g$ is increasing and $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are non-negative.

Comment: Your $F_x$ and $F_y$ should read $F_X$ and $F_Y$. (The error is obvious but it appears repeatedly on the site, and I have no idea why.)

Comment: @did Didier, thank you.  I've corrected the notation.  This shows the risks that arise when working from a cell phone.